# Calculating fees of creating new odoo modules that depends on existing built-in ones

Tags: module, odoo

I'm a new developer to odoo system, I use odoo 12

I need to create my own module lets say "Task Management" and it is expected to include around 60 users, which clearly depends on HR and accounting modules that odoo presents.

Actually, I'm a little confused,  since I need no more than 12 users for HR and accounting built-in odoo modules, and I need around 60 users for my own "task management" module, the question is: should I pay the fees for 60 users of odoo modules or just for 12 users, knowing that my module's users (60) should communicate with HR users (12)

I appreciate every suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has something to do with licensing of a software.

Comment: Besides voting to close it: you have to license all active users. The used apps have to be licensed independently. There is no connection to the app-using users.